# Get all media from certain upload location in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I have a front-end file uploader which (logically) allows my users to upload files from the website itself. (It restricts them to only upload pictures or certain text files). They can upload files from calendar items and wordpress automaticly adds that page title to the file.

So if i have a calendar item called : Meeting of the 21th of September 2012, and i upload, lets say, an image to that item. That file would be put in the backend of wordpress with the file location of: Meeting_of the_21th_of_September_2012. Now i want users to be able to watch these files from the location that they uploaded it from. (there are multiple users that can access the calendar, if person 1 uploads a file i want all the other people to see those files (in the front-end)).

Is it possible to show all media associated with a certain page with my certain setup? Is this at all possible?

Screenshot below is of an uploaded media file (its in dutch but the text 'Geupload naar:' means 'uploaded to:' (which is the name of the calendar page).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can display all media files.
You can do that by creating a folder by 'page name' or by 'id' and access all files from that folder.

or

You can store file id with page id in a database custom table or meta table and access the files from there.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to call for all media in that specific folder then? So if i create a folder 'test123' and i put my media in there. How do i "collect" all media from that folder?

Comment: Yes, You can read directory by "scandir" function.
 For better tutorial please visit this http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php